# Accessing all nav elements except for first and last?

Tags: html, css, razor

I have a nav within a unordered list, simplified html is like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
    etc ...
</ul>
```

The nav for this module has a dynamic amount of links so how can I change the border of the first and last element with some fancy css selector? i'm terrible with css so apologies in advance :x

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple ways you can do it, the easiest being the first-child and last-child selector.

```
li:first-child {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

li:last-child {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[Here's a JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsy70jt9/1/)

Comment: No but not all children are related to the menu. i need to target by specific class. in this case `.nav-child-1`, `.nav-child-2`, etc.

Comment: You would need to add that information to the question that you asked -- this is the first mention of it.

Comment: @Humility Your code sample in your post has no mention of classes. Can you update to give a better feel for what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but here are some options to get you started:

```
li { border: 1px solid red; }
li:first-child, li:last-child { border: none; }
```

or

```
li:first-child { border-top: 1px solid red; }
li:last-child { border-bottom: 1px solid red; }
```

or

```
ul { border: 1px solid red; border-width: 1px 0; }
```

Hope that gives you some ideas and piques your curiosity to learn more. =)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you need to use the :nth-child selectors

```
li:nth-child(1){}
li:nth-child(3){}
li:nth-child(4){}
li:nth-child(5){}
li:nth-child(6){}
```

or of course what everyone had already mentioned:

```
li:first-child{}
li:last-child{}
```

if there are any classes already assigned, then you use

```
.class-name{} /*where class name is the specific class*/
```

Anything more advanced and you need to use jS.